# checking values in a char multidimensional array, cpp

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char, strcmp, atoi

I am trying to check whether a user input matches a specific value in a char multidimensional array. But I cant seem to figure out a way to do so. The user input will be a number from 1-9. I will be looping through my array to find a matching value. My code is as follows,

```
 char input;
 getline(cin,input);
 char gameBoard[3][3] = {{'1','2','3'},
                         {'4','5','6'},
                         {'7','8','9'}
                        };
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        gameBoard[i][j];  //SOME CODE TO COMPARE THE VALUE TO USER INPUT
    }
}
```

I have tried using strcmp but can only do it for a single dimensional array.

I have also tried converting the char value into a number by atoi but i get an error,

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|
```

Any suggestions on how to compare will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I count at least three or four things that are wrong in this question. Looks to me like you're going too fast, with this C++ thing. Before tackling modestly sophisticated logic in this problem, it looks to me like you should go back and spent more time studied fundamentals. Like what it a char, what is a std::string, and which one of them is used by std::getline. What is a difference between a character and an integer, etc... If you still don't have a firm grasp on these fundamentals, trying to code a problem like this one will be pretty much impossible.

Comment: Robustly handling user input is notoriously difficult. You could use `geline()`, but you need a `std::string` for it as second argument. If you rely on the user to enter just one character (the number) per line, the test simply is `string s; getline(cin, s); if(s[0] == gameBoard[i][j])...`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik noted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

```
if (gameBoard[i][j] == input) {... }
```

Comment: I think the OP needds advice on how to obtain `input`.

Comment: yes this works thanks. I was trying too hard i guess.

Comment: @SafwanUllKarim If you are also wondering how to obtain `input`, `cin.get(input);` should work.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` expects a zero terminated string, not a character. If you need to compare whether a zero terminated string `str` is a single character `c`, you can use

```
(str[0] == c) && (str[1] == '\0')
```

In your case

```
if ((input[0] == gameBoard[i][j]) && (input[1] == '\0')) { /* ... */ }
```

The '\0' is the zero terminator of the string. It is important to check `str[0]` before `str[1]`, because `str` might be empty (i.e. `str[0] == '\0'`), and when reading past the end of the string (e.g. a value from `str[1]`), your program might crash.